S is not A but B = S is B but not A
Does the sentences "The point is not urgency but importance" and "The point is importance but not urgency" have same meaning?
Normally, we use the construction of the first sentence and I recognize it.
When I read the second sentence, I feel the meaning of it is somewhat different than the first one.

FYI, to me, the but sounds a bit off on the second. I think it would normally be phrased as The point is importance, not urgency.

Yes, jimm is spot on. The 'but' is required to establish the contrast in the << not A but B >> version (though an ellipsis and stress in speaking also works: << not A ... -B- >>). However, the need to signal a pause (the comma) in the << B, not A >> version means the 'but' is superfluous (and unidiomatic).

how can S is A be the same with S is B?

The difference is in the rhetorical usage. The reason we usually see the first version is because it dismantles whatever previous notions the audience had. The speaker is telling the audience that it's not the thing they initially thought, it is something else. Saying  "not urgency" in the second case makes  no sense, because you have already established what the point is, so we can assume that nothing else is the point.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Saying "not urgency" in the second case is of semantic (and certainly pragmatic) importance, to show/highlight what the contrasted element is. Though I'm not sure that OP's example couldn't be improved.
